# Problems using multiple where conditions to run specific criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am attempting to create a query that will allow me to run several table of information through a series of criteria however I can not seem to get this to work when it comes to using multiple WHERE clauses of the same type.

```
use leads;

select s.knum as Knum
    , s.customer_id as Cust_#
    , s.[full down] as FD_Date
    , s.season, s.inv as Room_Type
    , s.Owner_type
    , s.status
    , s.trw1
    , s.trw2
    , s.trw21
    , s.state
    , m.Knum as MagnaK
    , c.[pbs id] as MF_ID
    , c.[pbs disp] as MF_disp
    , c.[pbs freq] as Freq
    , c.[PBS DAYS DELQ] as MF_del
    , c.[PBS TOTAL DUE] as MF_Due
    , c.[LN ID]
    , c.[LN DISP]
    , c.[LN CURR BAL]
    , c.[LN NPDD]
    , st.customer_id as ST_custID
    , p.[LOAN #] as P_Knum
    , p.pmts_made as Paymnts_made
    , p.int
    , p.d30
    , p.d60
    , p.d90
    , d.knum as DVN_Knum
    , (
            select max(HighTrw) 
            from (values (trw1), (trw2), (trw21)) as Value(HighTrw)
        ) as [high_trw]
from dbo.spi s
LEFT JOIN dbo.magna m on s.knum = m.knum
LEFT JOIN dbo.book7 C on s.knum = C.K
LEFT JOIN dbo.spi_tours ST on s.customer_id = st.customer_id 
LEFT JOIN dbo.payments P on s.knum = P.[LOAN #]
LEFT JOIN dbo.dvn D on s.knum = d.knum
Where m.knum = null 
    and d.knum = null 
    and st.customer_id = null 
    or 
    (
        select max(HighTrw)
        from (values (trw1), (trw2), (trw21)) As updatedate (HighTrw)
    ) between 600 and 625 
    and p.current_bal >= '15000' 
    and p.CURRENT_Bal >= '7500' 
    or 
    (
        select max(HighTrw)
        from (values (trw1), (trw2), (trw21)) As updatedate (HighTrw)
    ) between 575 and 599 
    and p.current_bal >= '7499' 
    and p.CURRENT_Bal >= '5000';
```

I would like to be able to use the 6 tables linked in the code along with specific criteria to come up with a final list based on that criteria.

Comment: `{expression} =  NULL` is never going to work. Nothing equals `NULL`, including `NULL` itself.  `NULL` is an unknown value, and therefore cannot be "equal" to anything. If you need to compare to a `NULL` use `IS (NOT) NULL`.

Comment: All of the following expression will return "unknown": `1 = NULL`, `NULL = NULL`, `1 != NULL`, `NULL != NULL`. As a condition is always looking for it to evaluate to "true", the result "unknown", means that the expression is not "true"; which means that for your `WHERE` the row won't be returned as the `WHERE` did not evaluate to "true".

Comment: Aside from the huge = NULL issue you have several logical issues going on here as well. Your where predicates as mismatch of ANDs and ORs but there are no parenthesis at all. And since you don't use parenthesis you will never get any rows back with this because you have conflicting predicates in there.

Comment: I formatted your code so it easier to read and see what is going on.

Comment: I fixed the = null issue however the still remains. I can get the query to use the first where clause of between 15000 and 7500 however it will not work with the second of 7499 and 5000.

Comment: Because of your lack of parentheses (`()`) @jamesk. In your`WHERE` you also have 4 clauses where the value of `p.current_bal` has to be great than either `15000`, `7500`, `7499`, and `5000`. If something is greater than `7499` is is already greater than `5000`; so the clauses don't make sense. Why check for the latter when you already know it to be true?

Comment: You have no parenthesis. Therefore you don't have "groups" of criteria. You need to use parenthesis around the predicates you want to group.

Comment: Let me clarify. I am working on a criteria based on if the TWR is between x and Y and the p.current bal is between x and y I want those. Also if the TRW is between w and z  and the p.current_bal  is between d and f I also want those.

Answer (score 1):

There are several typos in your query. I've tried to format and simplify it to be able to correct it.

```
SELECT s.knum as Knum, 
    s.customer_id as Cust_#,
    s.[full down] as FD_Date, 
    s.season, 
    s.inv as Room_Type, 
    s.Owner_type, 
    s.status, 
    s.trw1, 
    s.trw2, 
    s.trw21, 
    s.state, 
    m.Knum as MagnaK,
    c.[pbs id] as MF_ID, 
    c.[pbs disp] as MF_disp, 
    c.[pbs freq] as Freq, 
    c.[PBS DAYS DELQ] as MF_del, 
    c.[PBS TOTAL DUE] as MF_Due, 
    c.[LN ID], 
    c.[LN DISP], 
    c.[LN CURR BAL], 
    c.[LN NPDD], 
    st.customer_id as ST_custID, 
    p.[LOAN #] as P_Knum, 
    p.pmts_made as Paymnts_made, 
    p.int, 
    p.d30, 
    p.d60, 
    p.d90, 
    d.knum as DVN_Knum, 
    v.HighTrw as [high_trw]
FROM      dbo.spi       s
LEFT JOIN dbo.magna     m  on s.knum = m.knum
LEFT JOIN dbo.book7     C  on s.knum = C.K
LEFT JOIN dbo.spi_tours ST on s.customer_id = st.customer_id 
LEFT JOIN dbo.payments  P  on s.knum = P.[LOAN #]
LEFT JOIN dbo.dvn       D  on s.knum = d.knum
CROSS APPLY (select max(HighTrw) 
            from (values (s.trw1), (s.trw2), (s.trw21))val(trw)) as v(HighTrw)
Where m.knum        IS NULL 
and d.knum          IS NULL 
and st.customer_id  IS NULL 
or (v.HighTrw between 600 and 625 and p.current_bal BETWEEN '7500' AND '15000')
or (v.HighTrw between 575 and 599 and p.current_bal BETWEEN '5000' AND '7499');
```

Comment: I wonder if it should be `customer_id IS NULL AND ((v.high...) OR (v.high...));`

Comment: My guess is the two lines you have with OR should be one of those two. Meaning AND (cond1 or cond2). But really hard to decipher the real need.

Comment: My guess is that either the 3 columns are NULL (no rows in those tables) or one of the other conditions are met. That's how my query rewrite should work.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess at your predicates is something like this.

```
Where m.knum IS null 
    and d.knum IS null 
    and st.customer_id IS null 
    AND
    (
        (
            select max(HighTrw)
            from (values (trw1), (trw2), (trw21)) As updatedate (HighTrw)
        ) between 600 and 625 
        and p.current_bal >= '15000' 
        and p.CURRENT_Bal >= '7500' 
    )
    OR 
    (
        (
            select max(HighTrw)
            from (values (trw1), (trw2), (trw21)) As updatedate (HighTrw)
        ) between 575 and 599 
        and p.current_bal >= '7499' 
        and p.CURRENT_Bal >= '5000'
    )
```

But that could be greatly simplified using CROSS APPLY to your values instead of doing it over and over.